# How do I get a Unique Identifier for a Device within Windows 10 Universal?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-10, win-universal-app

This is my old implementation to get a Unique DeviceID for Windows Universal 8.1 but the type HardwareIdentification does not exist anymore.

```
    private static string GetId()
    {
        var token = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
        var hardwareId = token.Id;
        var dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(hardwareId);

        byte[] bytes = new byte[hardwareId.Length];
        dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);

        return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "");
    }
```

Comment: FYI there's an even better way in the [Anniversary Update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40387615/how-to-get-unique-device-ids-on-windows-10-anniversary-update/40387616#40387616)

Comment: Is it possible to the see this same Id from windows, may be a commmand line or in the settings.?? I mean where does this hardware Id actually shows up.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That is the complete solution for Windows Desktop:

- Add the Extension reference "Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP" like Peter Torr - MSFT mentioned.

Use this Code to get the HardwareId:

```
using System;
using Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning;
using Windows.System.Profile;

namespace Tobit.Software.Device
{
    public sealed class DeviceInfo
    {
        private static DeviceInfo _Instance;
        public static DeviceInfo Instance
        {
            get {
                if (_Instance == null)
                    _Instance = new DeviceInfo();
                return _Instance; }

        }

        public string Id { get; private set; }
        public string Model { get; private set; }
        public string Manufracturer { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public static string OSName { get; set; }

        private DeviceInfo()
        {
            Id = GetId();
            var deviceInformation = new EasClientDeviceInformation();
            Model = deviceInformation.SystemProductName;
            Manufracturer = deviceInformation.SystemManufacturer;
            Name = deviceInformation.FriendlyName;
            OSName = deviceInformation.OperatingSystem;
        }

        private static string GetId()
        {
            if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification"))
            {
                var token = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
                var hardwareId = token.Id;
                var dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(hardwareId);

                byte[] bytes = new byte[hardwareId.Length];
                dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);

                return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "");
            }

            throw new Exception("NO API FOR DEVICE ID PRESENT!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea if... If you were to build an app or library targeting UWP used on both phone and desktop - can you use both phone and desktop SDKs or does it cause any problems with build, runtime or certification?

Comment: Hardware token can change if you add RAM to your PC, right ?

Comment: @Grigory I believe so, I recall I saw something on msdn like cpu id and Ram size are taken into account when generating the token.

Comment: @El I am getting different hardware id for same device

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar for multiple apps thats an expected behaviour i suggest. What context are you talking about?

Comment: @JensMarchewka I tried this code on Windows 10 IoT Core [Version 10.0.15063] (Raspberry PI 3) but the result of GetId() changes every time the device restarts. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Please see [this newer Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40387615/how-to-get-unique-device-ids-on-windows-10-anniversary-update) for a much better way to get an ID in more recent Windows builds.

Comment: @JensMarchewka Is there a way to get the same Id from different apps.? DO u have any idea to make a corelation between the app and the DeviceID. so that I can use a central server for both app and know there two devices are same

Answer (score 9):

## Update for Windows 1609 ("Anniversary Update")

See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40387615/how-to-get-unique-device-ids-on-windows-10-anniversary-update) for a much better way to get an ID.

## Old info for older OS builds

You need to add a reference to the Desktop and / or Mobile SDKs to build against the Hardware Token. At runtime you should use the `ApiInformation` type to query if the API is present before using it (other device families like Xbox don't have it).

That said, many times when people ask for the device ID that's not actually the best solution for their problem -- are you sure you need to identify the physical device across its entire lifespan, even if ownership changes?

Comment: No I just need some sort of ID witch is unique for identify the device on APP abuse to lock some functions of the APP. Also to associate the push Uri within our DB for this user (chat).

Comment: The device ID doesn't identify the user. It identifies the device. You need to implement another mechanism to generate and track user IDs (or rely on 3rd party login like Facebook or Microsoft Account)

Comment: That is exactly what we dont want. As you just can create new accounts to abuse our service again.

Comment: What do you do when the customer sells the device to someone else? Now they are associated with the wrong account.

Comment: Why would they be associated wrong? After 2 Month the abuse lock will be restored. Also it is possible to have more than one device within the same Account. We need to replace the Push-URI at our Push Server if it changes, so how would you identify the URI to replace for device X? I don't know why we need to discuss this, with Android & iOS it works very well, why would we want to change a running and tested system?

Comment: (1) Bob has a phone and abuses your app so you ban him. (2) Bob sells his phone to Alice. (3) Alice tries to use your app and is blocked for 2 months due to the ban on Bob's device.

Comment: Alice wont use the same Account. Alice is able to reach us on other ways to remove the lock earlier. But again, that's not the point.

Comment: Also I am wondering, won't the DeviceId change if the device gets reset? If not, isn't it a big security problem?

Comment: If the ID changed when the device was reset then your approach wouldn't work (Bob gets banned; Bob resets device; Bob is unbanned).

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT *You need to implement another mechanism to generate and track user IDs* - What's preferred? In my use case, I just want to keep track of API calls from installs of a consumer app, and make *reasonably* sure someone's not spamming/exploiting that cloud service. I could store a GUID in a local file and send it with each request, but would prefer a slightly obfuscated "real" hardware (or other built-in, unique) id so I'm not persisting info I don't need to. That doesn't call for a full-on Facebook/Google+/Passport ;) account login, I don't think.

Comment: Hardware Token is OK for that as long as you have mitigations for when the device is given to another user. If you are only banning DoS-type attacks (within a short time window) it should be OK.

Comment: Is it possible to the see this same Id from windows, may be a commmand line or in the settings.?? I mean where does this hardware Id actually shows up.?? @PeterTorr-MSFT

Comment: Is it possible to the see this same Id from windows, may be a commmand line or in the settings.?? I mean where does this hardware Id actually shows up. @JensMarchewka

Comment: No, because it is specific to an app - you could build an app that would show you *its* ASHWID, but that would be different than any other app's ASHWID.

Comment: I just thank to god that this windows phone thing is dead now.. the restrictions for developers have finally besiege the verdict

Comment: This API is not specific to Windows Phone.

Comment: Still to this day, i am really confused about why you wouldn't make it easier to catch an hardware id for a device, the hurdle of changing it is so much higher than getting accounts... While i surely admit it is not a perfect way to protect a service on that behalf, it is an easy approach, that may have been enough for many developers.

Comment: There have been many changes since 2018. UWP is less relevant (without phone) and desktop apps packaged with MSIX are allowed in the store (even raw Win32 apps can be listed, but not hosted). Also there are newer APIs like [System Identification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.profile.systemidentification?view=winrt-22621).

Answer (score 8):

It seems that

```
var deviceInformation = new EasClientDeviceInformation();
string Id = deviceInformation.Id.ToString();
```

is doing the magic, refering to [EasClientDeviceInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation.Id);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) it provides a unique Id.

> The Id property represents the DeviceId using the GUID truncated from the first 16 bytes of the SHA256 hash of the MachineID, User SID, and Package Family Name where the MachineID uses the SID of the local users group.

**BUT it only works for Windows Store Apps...** so there have to be another solution.

Comment: The EasClient ID is not the right solution for this. It's also not available across all device families so you need to reference the extension SDK.

Comment: Hi @EI Marchewko, Will `EasClientDeviceInformation` work for windows phone 10?

Answer (score 1):

EasClientDeviceInformation does not work for Windows 10 mobile. The device id is just the same for every phone (all our win10m customers gets registered with the same GUID) We need the id for sending push messages to the right phone.

Comment: Do we have solution for this? EasClientDeviceInformation  gives the same id for all phones

Answer (score 1):

```
//you can use this
//its working with me very fine on windows 10
//replace the word bios with any hardware name you want
//data also can be found with using windows application named (wbemtest) 

using System.Management;
public static async Task<string> ReturnHardWareID()
        {
            string s = "";
            Task task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher bios = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS");
                ManagementObjectCollection bios_Collection = bios.Get();
                foreach (ManagementObject obj in bios_Collection)
                {
                    s = obj["SerialNumber"].ToString();
                    break; //break just to get the first found object data only
                }
            });
            Task.WaitAll(task);

            return await Task.FromResult(s);
        }
```