# Unique Device ID UWP

Tags: c#, windows-phone, win-universal-app, uniqueidentifier

Since few days I am trying to get MAC Adress from my Windows Phone device withouse success. I am trying to get UNIQUE ID for my Phone, Tablet etc. I`ve found HardwareToken class and the code below

```
HardwareToken token = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
                IBuffer hardwareId = token.Id;
                HashAlgorithmProvider hasher = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("MD5");
                IBuffer hashed = hasher.HashData(hardwareId);
                string hashedString = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(hashed);
```

Using this code I am reciving **ASHWID**. Is that really unique?

Answer (score 2):

> Using this code I am receiving ASHWID. Is that really unique?

It depends. On phone/tablet more likely than on desktop. The exact answer you can found [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx):

> The ASHWID provides a strong binding between the app/package and the device by representing several individual hardware characteristics. In order to protect user privacy, the ASHWID varies from app to app. **Unless the underlying hardware has changed, two calls from the same app will result in identical ASHWIDs**. However, the ASHWID changes if the hardware profile of the device changes, such as when the user unplugs a USB Bluetooth adapter. The back-end cloud service can verify the ASHWID and compare it with previously reported values.

Following [Peter's Torr answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31749981/2681948) you should also check first if that API is present on actual device. Though you may also think about his advice - to think if that really is a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

the ASHWID is qualified as sufficiently unique. You can rely on it IMHO.
Check this reference article to get deep knowledge on the ASHWID
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj553431