# UWP System wide unique hardware or device ID

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, windows-runtime

Is there any other way to get hardware or device ID which is not dependent on package/app and publisher id's and also doesn't require usage of any restricted capabilities?

What I've already found:

- EasClientDeviceInformation. *Doesn't work on mobile devices*. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746613/how-do-i-get-a-unique-identifier-for-a-device-within-windows-10-universal?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- ASHWID. *Dependent on package/app*. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34153786/unique-device-id-uwp)
- SystemIdentification.GetSystemIdForPublisher. *Dependent on publisher id*. [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40387615/how-to-get-unique-device-ids-on-windows-10-anniversary-update) [Link 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.profile.systemidentification.getsystemidforpublisher)
- SystemIdentification.GetSystemIdForUser. *Requires restricted capability*. [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40387615/how-to-get-unique-device-ids-on-windows-10-anniversary-update)  [Link 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.profile.systemidentification.getsystemidforuser)
- SMBIOS. *Requires restricted capability*. [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt829374(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: http://puresourcecode.com/dotnet/post/How-do-I-get-a-Unique-Identifier-for-a-Device-within-Windows-10-Universal

Comment: But don't throw Exception, put your own exception instead, or at least throw another type of exception

Comment: These APIs are individualized or require restricted capabilities for privacy reasons. What purpose do you need the ID for?

Comment: @Peter Torr - MSFT I need ID to identify user PC independently of publisher ID.

Comment: What for? If it's for advertising, then the `AdvertisingId` is what you want.