# Which version of Windows SDK to install for UWP development?

Tags: uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am new in UWP development and started my first project using xamarin. I recently recognized that on my pc almost all versions of win SDKs are installed as shown below.

[image]

Do I really need all of them or only the latest version if my project is supporting min and max versions as in the image below?

According the images I don't have the min version 10240 but it is supported as shown, it looks like that higher version already covers the lower version. is that so?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about the answer to your question, but you have the SDK for 10240 installed. It is the "...Windows 10.0.26624".

Comment: @MarianDolinský this is strange. why they named it differently but it looks like you are right. when I check the download page, it looks like oldest version is like you said. so i suppose that it is 10240 https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support 10240 and target 14393, you'll at least need those 2 versions. Note that you can uninstall 10586 in Visual Studio even if you have the other 2 selected.

I do recommend you *changing your VS installation* and not delete SDKs from 'uninstall program'.

On another note, 10240 is rarely taken as minimum target these days, most often 10586 is picked (if not already 14393 as minimum as well to enabled some of the newest animations).

[image: VS update window]

---

UWP Build 10240 is actually versioned as 10.0.26624 (don't ask me why). Try re-installing that SDK explicitly and you'll get following error:

[image: Installation error 10240]

I noticed you have probably installed 10586 a while ago and it updated to a newer version. Similarly you already have an update of 14393. Whether you can uninstall 10586.15 or not, depends on whether the update is a complete overwrite or a partial update (my gut feeling would say the second, otherwise they could just remove the older version). To give you an idea, a 'full' 10586.212 is 2.15 GB. (I don't have an updated install on this machine to verify the update progress. I suppose only people from Microsoft can give a definitive answer on that part. But then again, as said before: update your VS installation, don't manually clean up SDKs.)

Comment: actually i found that 10586.212 is important version. I dont know why but i had a problem not installing 10586.212 completely. Indeed before I didnt have it installed and ended up having problem described on my this other ticket, you can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462048/hockeyapp-throws-exception-on-uwp-in-xamarin-forms-application

thats why I was so confused and i felt to write this question.

Comment: "if not already 14393 as minimum as well to enabled some of the newest animations".. do you mean that in order to get newest animations, I need to set 14393 as minimum?

Comment: beside that why do you say use VS installation? My experience tells me other way around. I did my first installation using vs installer and vs installer messed up things for example, it doesnt display you what tools are installed like standalone installer. It was showing me 10586.212 was installed but when I right clicked in installed programs and selected "change" option, i saw that it just installed "windows app certification kit" but not others in the list. I guess this happened because i tried to install all versions at the same time.

Comment: later I just uninstalled all from listed programs and went to the page https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive and installed one by one without any problem. not sure what other experience you had. I would like to know if you kindly share.

Comment: I always installed through the VS installer (separate upgrades or even a full repave with all versions last week), never had an issue. Installing out of VS should be fine, but uninstalling I wouldn't risk (as you don't know what is referenced by what).
About the newest animations: for eg. DropShadow you will need 14393.