# Identify a device from UWP App & .NET Framework Windows Service

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Is there any value that identifies a system (windows 10 desktop device) which can be read both from a UWP app and from a Windows Service written in .NET Framework ?

I already considered:

- **Computername** > To unsecure and can be faked to easily
- **ASHWID** > Not available in .NET Framework
- **Network Snapshot** (Read all Network Adapter addresses and build a magic string) > Works but changes every time a network was switched

Any other identifier that is accessible from both worlds on a single system?

**Background:** The app consists of three components. A Windows Service, a UWP App and a cloud broker. On first connection, the service and the UWP App do a handshake over the cloud broker. For this initial handshake an identifier must be submitted so both can then exchange a secure token.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: UWP apps run in a sandbox you're not going to get any uniquely identifying information about the hardware or the OS.

Comment: ASHWID is such a ID. I don't need to identify the machine - I just need to know if service and UWP app are on the same machine for a handshake.

Comment: See [How to get a unique ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40387615/how-to-get-unique-device-ids-on-windows-10-anniversary-update) - should work from an NT service if it is running as the same user as the app, but I haven't personally tried it. If the service is running under a different account... hmm you could look at RPC for the app to ping the service.

Comment: What about MAC address?