# Generate unique hardware Serial in windows 10 Iot Core?

Tags: c#, uwp, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

how can get device hardware info and generate a unique value with combining them ?
for example i want a generate a unique code with (CPU serial number + ram serial number + ethernet mac address or etc) 
so how can i get CPU  or Ram serial number in UWP ?

Comment: why not use the method already provided to get a `SystemIdentificationInfo` object? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.profile.systemidentification

Comment: I don't think you can get this information in a UWP app, i think you need to reevaluate the problem

Comment: @Saruman, that API is specifically designed for UWP. Also, see [this Question & Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40387615/how-to-get-unique-device-ids-on-windows-10-anniversary-update)

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT i use `SystemIdentificationInfo` with Registery source but when the device is reset the Id changed!

Comment: Did you try any of the other sources? You can get MAC address if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find **HardwareIdentification** class in ***Windows.System.Profile*** namespace for generate UniqueID.

```
   var token = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
   using (DataReader reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(token.Id))
   {
       byte[] bytes = new byte[token.Id.Length];
       reader.ReadBytes(bytes);
       string uniqueCode = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
   }
```

For more information you can see [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.profile.hardwareidentification)

To do that make sure you enable **TPM** on your target device, for enabling TPM you must installed it from **TPM Configuration Tab** in Windows device portal.

**Tips :** Raspberry pi doesn`t have any internal TPM so you must select ***Software TPM Emulator (NoSecurity)*** then install it, for Intel minnow board max and qualcomm dragonboard you can choose other options. after set and install **TPM** the device reboot, when it boot again the generated code which you can see on top always be unique.

Answer (score -2):

This is not a complete answer but,
You can find CPU serial number by using following code,

```
string cpuInfo = string.Empty;
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("win32_processor");
ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();

foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
{
     cpuInfo = mo.Properties["processorID"].Value.ToString();
     break;
}
```

Comment: You can't use this dll with UWP application

Comment: i know this, but cannot use it in UWP!