# How do I get a Unique Identifier for a Raspberry PI within Windows 10 IoT Core (Creators Update)

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

I tried this Method (found on https://stackoverflow.com/a/31803247/2427812) on Windows 10 IoT Core [Version 10.0.15063] (Raspberry PI 3) to get the HardwareId but the result of GetId() changes every time the device restarts.
Do you have any idea why this should happen?

```
private static string GetId()
{
    if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification"))
    {
        var token = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
        var hardwareId = token.Id;
        var dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(hardwareId);

        byte[] bytes = new byte[hardwareId.Length];
        dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);

        return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "");
    }

    throw new Exception("NO API FOR DEVICE ID PRESENT!");
}
```